# Proper Rails Association to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I am trying to create an association between two tables. A student table and a computer table.
A computer can only ever be assigned to one student (at any one time) but a student can be assigned to multiple computers.

This is what I currently have in mind. Setting up a has-many through relationship and modifying it a bit.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignemnts
  has_many :computers, :through => :assignments
end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :assignment
 has_one :student, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :computer
end
```

Does this seem like the best way to handle this problem? Or something better sound out quickly to the experts here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to decide if a simple one-to many relationship is enough for you.

If yes, it gets a lot easier, because you can get rid of the Assignment-class and table.

Your database-table "computers" then needs a student_id column, with a non-unique index

Your models should look like this:

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :computers, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

"dependent nullify" because you don't want to delete a computer when a student is deleted, but instead mark it as free.

Each of your computers can only be assigned to a single student, but you can reassign it to a different student, for example in the next year.

Comment: this actually seems like the best solution, it made the code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use has_and_belongs_to_many method. In your case it will be:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignemnts
    has_and_belongs_to_many :computers, :join_table => 'assignments',
end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :assignment
    has_and_belongs_to_many :student, :join_table => 'assignments',
end
```

or you can rename assignments table to computers_students and remove join_table

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignemnts
    has_and_belongs_to_many :computers
end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :assignment
    has_and_belongs_to_many :student
end
```

Comment: i think table name should be computers_students

Comment: Yes, you have to follow lexical order of the class names.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your approach is fine, as one offered by `@alexkv`. It is more discussion, than question.

Another thing if you want to use mapping table for some other purposes, like storing additional fields - then your approach is the best thing. In `has_many :through` table for the join model has a primary key and can contain attributes just like any other model.

**From api.rubyonrails.org:**

> Choosing which way to build a many-to-many relationship is not always
>   simple. If you need to work with the relationship model as its own
>   entity, use has_many :through. Use has_and_belongs_to_many when
>   working with legacy schemas or when you never work directly with the
>   relationship itself.

I can advise you read this, to understand what approach better to choose in your situation:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
- http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off